# Saving objects in memcache using objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have already tried using objectify to manage my app engine data store. I find my entities using load operation and i modify a field in my entity but i don't save it.

i retrieve the same entity with another load operation and i see that the field is updated knowing that i don't save the entity.

is it the session cache of objectify, is it the core cache of objectify responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Do you have the ObjectifyFilter installed?

Comment: Yes , Sure. it's the first step

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this within the same request then yes, you are seeing the session cache.

See:  https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Caching

Comment: Thanks, yes i used in the same request (i mean the same method). if i have to retain some information about my User object how can i do it through many methods. Can i use the GWT session or other thing to solve my problem ??